# Wordpress - Como pegar o thumbnail em uma tag HTML com CSS e PHP?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tenho um CSS que é assim:

```
.cid-rlWhG48NmK {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background-image: url("../../images/background4.jpg");
}
```

E meu HTML chama desta forma:

```
<section class="mbr-section content5 cid-rlWhG48NmK mbr-parallax-background" id="content5-f">
...
```

Quero implementar o `get_the_post_thumbnail()` no `cid-rlWhG48NmK` mudando a imagem: **Se tiver imagem destacada, então usar, senão, utilizar uma padrão.**

Estou tentando desta forma:

```
    <style>
    <?php if(get_the_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
        .cid-rlWhG48NmK {
            background-image: url('<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>')>;
        }
    <?php else : ?> 
        .cid-rlWhG48NmK {
            background-image: url('<?php bloginfo($show = ´template_url´); ?>/assets/images/background4.jpg');
        }
    <?php endif; ?>
</style>

<section class="mbr-section content5 cid-rlWhG48NmK mbr-parallax-background" id="content5-f">
```

Mas não está pegando nem a imagem destacada e nem a definida no caso contrário.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

**PS:** Eu retiro do CSS o background-image para fazer o código que desejo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pegar a url da thumbnail é so usar a função: `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` recomendo colocar ela inline no html, exemplo:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
}
else {
    $img = 'caminh_imagem_padrao'.png
}
?>

    <section class="mbr-section content5" id="content5-f" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $img ?>);">
```

Comment: Glaydson Rodrigues, deu certo! Muito Obrigado! :)